# ASP.net do not cache page with a specific querystring

Tags: asp.net, caching, query-string

I know that i can use the VaryByParam attribute, but what it does is not exactly what i am aiming for.

What happens is that different versions of the page are cached based on the query string.

For example Page.aspx?ID=Tom has its own cached version and ID=Arnold has another. Now what i want to do is not to cache Arnold at all. I only want to cache the page when the query string is Tom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub CacheOutput(ByVal Page As Page, ByVal Minutes As Integer)
        Page.Response.Cache.SetExpires(Date.Now.AddMinutes(Minutes))
        Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server)
        Page.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(True)
    End Sub
```

This works. Note that any version of the page that has a querystring or a POST parameter will not be cached.

Answer (score 1):

For C#

```
    public static void cacheOutput(Page page, double minutes)
    {
        page.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes));
        page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
        page.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
    }
```

It's better to take a double for minutes.
Good solution! 
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use VaryByCustom and override GetVaryByCustomString method in the Application class.